# Issue linking Azure API to C# ASP.Net project in Visual Studio 2019 Community

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2019

I'm having an issue linking up to an Azure API within Visual Studio. It seems like I'm missing multiple options from the Connected Services menu. For example, these are the options I have :

[image: these are the options I have]

While all the documentation shows many more options

[image: all the documentation shows many more options]

Another example is this:

what I see :

[image: what I see]

what the documentation shows :

[image: what the documentation shows]

I'm certain I've just missed something, can someone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: Did you thought about clicking that find more services link to see what it does?

Comment: The second two screenshots are after clicking "find more services" :(

Comment: You might not have installed them at the time visual studio installer offered it. Download the package and try again maybe?

Comment: Done that :(, still no luck

Comment: Hello, Can you provide the document that you are referring to?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/cognitive-services/face/vs-face-connected-service

Comment: Hello, Thanks for providing the link. I was able to reproduce the issue as well, I have reached out to the internal Product team and I will get back to you with any response I may get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reached out to internal product team and found that this extension is no longer supported. The documentation has been updated to reflect this and the extension is retired from the marketplace.